# SQL Server Profiler error in the metadata manager. Either the trace with the ID of 'MicrosoftProfilerTrace...' does not exist in the server

Tags: sql-server, ssas

When I try to start a new trace in SQL Server Profiler **(Analysis Services)**, I get the following Error:

Error in the metadata manager. Either the trace with the ID of 
'MicrosoftProfilerTrace...' does not exist in the server with the ID
'ServerName', or the user does not have  permissions to access to the object.

Comment: which version of sql server? trace working well with SSAS on SQL server 2014 and 2012.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Standard

Answer (score 0):

Try this: go to path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn, then run PROFILER.exe as Administrator, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the Dataset name(Now semantic Model) in connection properties helped to solve this error.

More info -
https://shabnamwatson.com/2022/11/06/error-running-a-sql-server-profiler-trace-for-a-power-bi-dataset-either-the-trace-with-the-id-of-microsoftprofilertrace1667261566-does-not-exist/